# Is there a way to get the highest number of occurrence of elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, collections

I have this sample function to get the most voted names in List,..
It should be as simple as below if only i know the names of those in the list.

```
public static String getHighestVotes(final List<String> votedNames) {

    int a = Collections.frequency(votedNames, "Ann");
    int b= Collections.frequency(votedNames, "Annie");
    int c = Collections.frequency(votedNames, "Ana");

   //some logic code here..  

    return "";
}
```

However, I did not so the code below is of no use. And though i can do this one in some ways.. doing for loops etc. the performance would be my issue if in case the length of the List would go for about millions.
   So is there anyway to cut down the work for this one? Or i should really go for counting Unique and so on.

Comment: You only need one loop that populates a map where you count the occurrences (map key will be the name, value the number of times it's been encountered). Then you pick the map entry with the highest occurrence.

Answer (score 3):

take your list of Names and add it to a Map. for example:

```
Map<String, Integer> res = new HashMap<>();
votedNames.forEach( s -> {
  if(res.get(s) == null) // initialize
  // increment count for word
});
```

Result will be a hashmap with the count for each word.

Comment: Or using a reduction instead: `Map<String, Long> res = votedNames.stream().collect(groupingBy(n -> n, counting()));`

Comment: Or `Map<String, Integer> res = new HashMap<>(); for (String s : votedNames) res.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);`

Answer (score 3):

You do have an easy option with Java8:

```
    Map<String, Long> result = votedNames.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, 
                           Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You said List would contain millions of data in that case using `paralleStream()` would be advantageous here instead of `stream()`.

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList < String > ();

for (int i = 1; i <= 3000; i++)
 list.add("a");

for (int i = 1; i <= 2000; i++)
 list.add("b");

for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
 list.add("c");

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

Map <String, Long> countListSequence = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time taken by stream() " + (end - start) + " millisec data " + countListSequence);

long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

Map <String, Long> countListparallel = list.parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));

long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time taken by parallelStream() " + (end1 - start1) + " millisec data " + countListparallel);
```

Output

```
Time taken in by stream() 93 millisec data {a=3000, b=2000, c=1000}
Time taken by parallelStream() 11 millisec data {a=3000, b=2000, c=1000}
```